# submitting arabic content through form cause forbidden page

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Hi there I have a form that send my data from admin panel.
it has one input that represent title of my site

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="do" name="do" value="save">
        <input value="site title" type="text" class="form-control" id="sitename" name="sitename" placeholder="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button>
</form>
```

and use this to submit the form in my database

```
switch($_GET['do'])
    {
        default:

            $this->updateSettings( array(
                   'sitename' => $this->secureInput($_POST['sitename'])
                                        ) );        
        break;
}

public function updateSettings($settingsArr)
{

    foreach($settingsArr as $varname => $value)

        $this->query("UPDATE ".TP."settings SET value = '$value' WHERE varname = '$varname'");

}
```

this form works fine if I entered an english title in the input but if I entered arabic title in it, it give me a page

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /adminpanel on server

how to solve this problem

Comment: try with : $this->query("UPDATE ".TP."settings SET value = ' ".$value." ' WHERE varname = ' ".$varname." ' ");

Comment: What does `secureInput()` do?

Comment: If anything went fatally wrong in your code, then you should probably rather get a 500 Internal Server Error. So this might(!) be something else interfering, before it even comes to execution of your own script. Check with your server admin / hoster, if anything filtering for “bad” input might happen on that level maybe.

Comment: What's up with the `switch()`? It's seem a bit redundant.

Comment: @Sachin I think it does not require this it works for english well

Comment: @empiric  public function secureInput($input, $html = true)
 {
  
  return $this->db()->escape_string( !$html ? $input : strip_tags($input) );
  
  
 }

Comment: @misorude .i am using this function to input parameters to database...  public function secureInput($input, $html = true)
 {
  
  return $this->db()->escape_string( !$html ? $input : strip_tags($input) );
  
  
 }

Comment: @MagnusEriksson . i am using more than on page for setting page there are more cases but i removed because it does not matter in my problem

Comment: can you echo this value UPDATE ".TP."settings SET value = '$value' WHERE varname = '$varname'  and then run this in your phpmyadmin. let see if its update from direct phpmyadmin or not.

Comment: @Sachin i used this in php my admin UPDATE `c4p_settings` SET `value` = 'دورات تدريبية' WHERE `varname` = 'sitename' and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works fine when i updated the charset of column 'value' in 'c4p_settings' table to utf8_general_ci   and use the following formula

```
$this->query("UPDATE ".TP."settings SET value = ' ".$value." ' WHERE varname = ' ".$varname." ' ");
```

instead of this formula

```
$this->query("UPDATE ".TP."settings SET value = '$value' WHERE varname = '$varname'");
```

thanks to @Sachin